# Why doesn't this code work streaming a song using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, media-player

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out, any suggestion is welcome:

```
NSURL *songUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a1804.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/064/Music/v4/9b/b3/c7/9bb3c7dc-a06f-f18c-3e41-2ce1e36f73b4/mzaf_7432104896053262141.aac.m4a"];

MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:songUrl];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)

                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification

                                           object:nil];



[mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];

[mp setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];

[mp setFullscreen:YES];



[self.view addSubview:[mp view]];



[mp prepareToPlay];

[mp play];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be more useful if you said *what* your problem was in your original question.

But I compiled your code into a test app on my side and found the problem pretty quick ([especially after looking at this related question and it's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396719/adding-an-mpmovieplayercontroller-in-full-screen-mode)).

To solve the problem *I think* you are having, add this line of code somewhere before adding the Movie Player subview to the parent view:

```
[mp.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
```

And the controller should appear in proper full screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` instead of `MPMoviePlayerController`.