# App getting crashed when video is entered in full screen mode in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an application where I am displaying a video on a view. But when the video is displayed it is getting crashed when I click on the full screen mode in iOS. This is my code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

MPMoviePlayerController *mc = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:nil];

    mc.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    mc.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    NSURL *contentURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"01 01. Welcome" withExtension:@"mov"];
    mc.contentURL = contentURL;
    [mc prepareToPlay];
    mc.view.frame = self.test.bounds;
    [self.test addSubview:mc.view];
    self.testvideo = mc;
     testvideo.fullscreen=YES;
}
```

I am adding player controller on to another view named test. When I click on the full screen buttons the app is getting crashed displaying error messages:

```
-[UIView trackRectForBounds:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa171ec0
2013-09-03 15:49:35.178  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView trackRectForBounds:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa171ec0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your app is crashing in the code snippet you've provided because the trackRectForBounds method is found on the UISlider class. Are you using a slider anywhere in your app ?

I'd suggest you to try the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` class instead of the `MPMoviePlayerController` class.

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396719/adding-an-mpmovieplayercontroller-in-full-screen-mode?rq=1) SO question for more details.